# Finding shutdown event in Android bug reports

Tags: logging, shutdown, bug-report-feature

My Phone which runs on Android 11 has been crashing frequently. This happens randomly - while attending a call or playing a video.

I have tried to report it to my manufacturer multiple times to no avail.
So, I decided to take and analyse the Android bug report in order to understand what is causing the issue. The bug report generates a zip file - which consists of a txt file containing logs.

Is there any generic message which is logged by Android before initiating a shutdown? Or is there any other way - any bug report analysis tool in which I can isolate the events around the crash?

Answer (score 0):

You could link your phone to Android Studio.  It has a logcat display that shows exceptions from everything, not just your app.  If your phone resets while connected, you'll have a running log of everything up to the reset.  In Android 11, it natively supports wireless ADB so you can do this wirelessly.

Comment: Hello. A crucial part of the question has remained unanswered, which is: "*Is there any generic message which is logged by Android before initiating a shutdown? Or is there any other way - any bug report analysis tool in which I can isolate the events around the crash ?*" Logcat throws all sorts of log output. One needs to know what they are looking for in that hay of logs.

Comment: logcat would quit logging when the phone resets.  Whether or not the final log could even be logged is up for debate anyway.  Logcat has many useful features making it easier to peruse including filters.  There's not a whole lot more that can be done here since he isn't capturing errors from his own program.